# Plot axis labels obscured when using mfrow in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

When I use `mfrow` to create 2x2 regression diagnostic plots, labels are obscured by the margins of the quartz window and by the margins of the plots themselves.

Admittedly this is not my code, but it is my data. I suspect it has everything to do with the margin settings, but I am largely unsure of what I am doing.

```
opar <- par(mfrow=c(2,2), mex=0.6, mar=c(4,4,3,2)+.3)
plot(amod1, which=1:4)
par(opar)
```

I can't post an image of the graphic apparently.

`amod1` is a generalized linear model given by the code below. `RHT1` is a dataframe of tabulated artifact count data.

```
amod1 = glm(x1 ~ y1, data = RHT1, family = poisson)
```

Comment: You don't say what amod1 is, so I used an example from `lm` and it worked fine. Can you give details of amod1?

Comment: Just edited the post to answer your question, hopefully.

Comment: make the window bigger before plotting

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it did not help. I will see if I can get an example uploaded.

Comment: I can't answer the question because my reputation is still low (just joined this StackExchange). To solve this problem I increased the values of the bottom, left, and top margins as shown in the code below. I also changed the value at the end of the command from +.3 to +.1. The plot labels now display correctly.

`opar <- par(mfrow=c(2,2), mex=0.6, mar=c(5,5,4,2)+.1)
plot(amod1, which=1:4)
par(opar)`

Comment: Hi @J_L glad you figured it out.